# How is the output 15 here? can someone explain it to me? I didn't really understand the use of putc and stdout

Tags: c, stdout, putchar

```
     int *z;
 char *c = "123456789";
 z = c;
 
 putc(*(z++),stdout);
 putc(*z, stdout);
 
 return 0;
```

The output is 15 thats for certain but how does this happen.

Comment: You've used the wrong pointer type, which expects the size of each element to be `4`. Adding `1` to (or incrementing) a pointer adds the size of its type. So the outputs are `'1'` and `'5'` with no spacing between.

Comment: It's moderately certain on little-endian machines; it would not be the output on a big-endian machine.  You have UB assigning the string pointer to the `int *z`.  Your compiler should be complaining.  Pointers increment by the size of the type it points at — `int` is 4 bytes on your machine.  So, when you increment `z`, it moves by 4 bytes, and `5` comes 4 bytes after `1` in that string.

Comment: Consider that `z++` is equivalent to `z = z + 1` which is the same as `z = (char *)z + sizeof *z`, which (on your particular platform) appears to be the same as `z = (char *)z + 4`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this code operation by operation. For this reason I have rewritten it (both codes are equivalent):

```
int *z;
char *c = "123456789";
z = c;

putc(*z, stdout);
z++;
putc(*z, stdout);
```

Because you use `z++`, the post increment, `++z` would be pre-increment, the value of `z` is fetched, before incrementing it.

After the first three lines everything looks as expected. Both pointers point to the string "123456789". But the first `putc` is already interesting. `z` is a pointer to an integer, but it points to a character, so fetching the pointer value fetches 4 bytes instead of one. Because you are using a little endian machine, the the 3 higher bytes are truncated by converting the integer (with the bytes "1234" = 875770417) to a character. The lowest byte ('1' = 49) remains.

In the line `z++;`, not 1, but 4 is added to the address `z` points to, because `z` is expected to point to an integer with the size of 4 bytes. On your system an `int` has apparently 4 bytes. So instead of pointing to "23456789" it points to "56789". This is just how pointer arithmetic work in C.

The last line works exactly like the 5th, but this time `z` points to "5678" (= 943142453) which gets truncated to 53 (= '5'). On big endian machines, the code would print "48" instead.